# Cannot insert value into database?(ERROR:The database file is locked)

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I created a sqlite database in unity... and tried to  connect with this function.

```
void AddScores(string conn)
    {
        IDbConnection dbconn;
        dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(conn);
        dbconn.Open();

        using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbconn.CreateCommand())
        {
            //    string sqlQuery = "SELECT Id FROM PickAndPlace ";
            string sqlQuery= "INSERT INTO PickAndPlace (Id) VALUES (324)";
            dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using(IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    print(reader.GetInt32(0));
                }
                dbconn.Close();
                reader.Close();
                dbCmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

The following code not working if I try **insert** values...and it is showing this error *"The database file is locked:
database is locked"* But If I try  **select** this works fine.So where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite generally accepts a single "connection". Once one application connects to the database, which means just acquiring a write lock on it, no other applications can access it for writes, but can access it for reads. Which is just the behaviour you are seeing. See [File Locking And Concurrency Control in SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) for a bunch more details about how this works, the various locking states etc.

But in principle, you can only have a single connection open. So somehow you have more than one. Either you forget to close some connections, or multiple threads or applications are trying to modify it. Or perhaps some error occurred and left the locking files in a bad state.